# Unable to update client webpage after receiving reply from WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-3.5

I'm working on some application which is in ASP.Net 3.5 in which I've to embed a new feature called Instant Messaging/ Push Notification.
For this, I've used WCF to send data to client.
But the issue is, when WCF sends data to client at that time I'm unable to use it at client in asp page like I can't display it in web page or unable to update my page by using the data send by WCF.

I've tried

```
Response.Write(sendData);  //sendData is the data which is send by WCF
```

just to write data on page,
But, Its also throwing an exception:

"Response is not available in this context."

So, please let me know how can I use sendData in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use HttpContext.Current.Response in a code where there is no current response.

If this is used in an HTTPHandler, you need to use the Context object passed through the ProcessRequest method in the IHTTPHandler interface.

Further, you can see [here](http://mvolo.com/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-applicationstart)

Comment: I'm using it inside .aspx page because I've to update client's current page state.
I've already read Mike Volodarsky's blog but this is not helpful in my case.